# How to "unset" variables in an array - Angular?

Tags: angular

I was creating an array of data and each instanciation of data is the same.
In my case, I am working on calendars to let people create date range.
But, these ranges are all "SET" to the same variable.
So in my case, if I change the values (start date, end date) of a calendar line, the other line would be impacted too.
I was wondering how I can "unset" (that's not the right terme but I imagine these as variables set to the same values) each line.

I put my code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swrr7s-jiyfdz?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.ts) but my ts file would look like:

```
calendars: { start: Date; end: Date }[];
  calendar: { start: Date; end: Date };
  today = Date.now();
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(),
    end: new FormControl(),
    nights: new FormControl()
  });
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  form: FormGroup;
  i: number;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.calendar = { start: null, end: null };
    this.calendars = [this.calendar];
    this.form = new FormGroup({});
  }

  addCalendar() {
    this.calendars.push(this.calendar);
    console.log(this.calendars);
  }
```

and my html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let calendar of calendars; let i = index;">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
      <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
      <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="removeCalendar(i)">Delete a calendar</button>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="addCalendar()">Add a calendar</button>
```

I thought each instanciation would be unique and independant of each others.
How can I unset these "variables"?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can call `reset()` on FormGroup or the FormControl - Function definition:

`Resets the FormGroup, marks all descendants pristine and untouched and sets the value of all descendants to null.`

in your case that would be `this.range.reset()`

e.g.

```
resetRange() {
   return this.range.reset();
}
```

UPDATE: Here is a stackblitz in which we use new instance of FormGroup for each calendar.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swrr7s-pvxrrd?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.ts

Comment: thanks a lot. It really helped me on that.